# ESP8266 Keeps Rebooting rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,7) NO PROGRAM LOADED

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, esp8266

I'm new with the ESP8266. Today I bought one and found a tutorial to connect it in this way

[image: ARDUINO WIRING]

The wiring is made without the microprocessor of Arduino as you may see in the picture. When I connected it this way the Serial COM of the Arduino IDE, at 9600 baud sends this:

```
ö,2Yâ@ÈH
+ôÈLÃ<(ÔŒÐ�ÀÀŒŽ¡C¡¥µThinker Technology Co. Ltd.

invalid
```

and at 115200 baud this pops on

```
  ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,7)
 wdt reset load

 **0x40100000, len 816, room 16 

 tail 0 

chksum 0x8d

 load 0x3ffe8000, len 788, room 8 

 tail 12

 chksum 0xcf 

ho 0 tail 12 room 4 

load 0x3ffe8314, len 288, room 12 

 tail 4

 chksum 0xcf 

csum 0xcf 

2nd boot version : 1.2 
 SPI Speed      : 40MHz  
 SPI Mode       : QIO  
 SPI Flash Size : 4Mbit

jump to run user1**
```

I really don't know whats going on, an it keeps rebooting or doing this repeatedly.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This way you doing (without the atmega328) and connecting rx-rx and tx-tx you are setting the ESP to be programmed or burn a new firmware. The messages are right to the ESP module with a standard firmware. Look this [tutorial](http://iot-playground.com/blog/2-uncategorised/67-arduino-esp8266-ide), instead of use a FTDI programmer your are using the arduino boart, pretty much the same.

Comment: But to the guy in the tutorial it worked pretty well, in my case i can put some AT commands that will work but have no effect on my problem(AT+RST//AT)

Comment: probably are different firmwares. Its ok if you cant use the AT commands doesn't mean the ESP isn't working.